# Density Plot Not Printing The Entire Range

Tags: plotting, color

I have a density function running on a piecewise function. When I plot the x range for full 0 to 1, the upper right corner color range doesn't print, but it works when I plot the x range for that higher end of range. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Post the actual code (InputForm) rather than its image so that we can execute the code.